# Painting JPanel/JComponent

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

Hello I have a problem with painting a picture on a panel and adding it on frame.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class CardComponent extends JPanel {
int x;int y;
String[] str = {
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Clubs_Ace.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Clubs_King.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Clubs_Queen.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Clubs_Jack.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Clubs_10.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Clubs_9.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Clubs_8.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Clubs_7.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Clubs_6.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Clubs_5.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Clubs_4.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Clubs_3.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Clubs_2.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Diamonds_Ace.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Diamonds_King.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Diamonds_Queen.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Diamonds_Jack.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Diamonds_10.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Diamonds_9.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Diamonds_8.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Diamonds_7.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Diamonds_6.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Diamonds_5.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Diamonds_4.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Diamonds_3.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Diamonds_2.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Hearts_Ace.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Hearts_King.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Hearts_Queen.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Hearts_Jack.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Hearts_10.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Hearts_9.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Hearts_8.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Hearts_7.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Hearts_6.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Hearts_5.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Hearts_4.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Hearts_3.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Hearts_2.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_Ace.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_Ace.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_King.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_Queen.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_Jack.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_10.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_9.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_8.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_7.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_6.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_5.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_4.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_3.png",
           "D:\\Images\\ImageCards\\Spades_2.png"      
           };
   Image img;
     public CardComponent(int x,int y) {
         setOpaque(false);
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
         setSize(100,150);
         setVisible(true);


     }
     public void paint(Graphics g) {
         super.paint(g);
         Random r = new Random();
         String s = "";
         s = str[r.nextInt(str.length)];
         img = getToolkit().getImage(s);
         g.drawImage(img,this.x , this.y, 100, 150, this);
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         CardComponent cc = new CardComponent(10,150);
         JFrame jfrm = new JFrame();
         jfrm.setSize(100, 150);
         jfrm.setVisible(true);
         jfrm.getContentPane().add(cc);
     }
 }
```

In class upper is the main problem (can't paint card).And I added this thing to the main frame(code lower).I added method main in every class just to check if it works right.
            import java.awt.Button;
      import java.awt.Color;
      import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
      import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

```
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.JSlider;
  import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
  import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


  public class PanelButtons extends JPanel{
Button but1;
Button but2;
    Button but3;
JLabel jlab;
JSlider jsl;
public PanelButtons() {
     setLayout(null);  
     Color c = new Color(0,120,0);
     setSize(700,200);
     setLocation(0,0);
     setOpaque(false);
     but1 = new Button("Check");
     but1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
     but1.setLocation(660, 350);
     but1.setBounds(683, 650, 70, 40);
     add(but1);
     but2 = new Button("Fold");
     but2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
     but2.setLocation(660, 350);
     but2.setBounds(753, 650, 70, 40);
     add(but2);
     but3 = new Button("Bet");
     but3.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
     but3.setLocation(660, 350);
     but3.setBounds(823, 650, 70, 40);
     add(but3);
     int money = Player.PremierMoney();
     jsl = new JSlider(0,1000);
     jsl.setMajorTickSpacing(50);
     jsl.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
     jsl.setLabelTable(jsl.createStandardLabels(100));
     jsl.setPaintTicks(true);
     jsl.setPaintLabels(true);
     jsl.setSize(400, 150);
     jsl.setBackground(c);
     jlab = new JLabel("Ваша ставка"+jsl.getValue());
     jsl.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
            if(jsl.getValueIsAdjusting()) return;
            jlab.setText("Ваша ставка:"+jsl.getValue());

        }

     });
     jlab.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
     jlab.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
     jsl.setLocation(900,600);
     jlab.setLocation(150,150);
     add(jsl);
     add(jlab);
     but2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


         @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             but1.setEnabled(false);
             but2.setEnabled(false);
             but3.setEnabled(false);

        }
     });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Some frame");
    jfrm.setSize(200, 200);
    PanelButtons pb = new PanelButtons();
    jfrm.setContentPane(pb);
    jfrm.setVisible(true);
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(jfrm.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
   }
```

This class describes buttons and slider.
        import java.awt.Color;
        import javax.swing.JFrame;

```
    public class Images extends JFrame{
   Images() {
      // CardComponent cc = new CardComponent(530,550);
       PanelButtons pb = new PanelButtons();
       Color c = new Color(0,120,0);
    //  cc.setBounds(530, 550, 100, 150);
      setSize(1366,750); 
      setBackground(c);
      setContentPane(pb);
    //  setContentPane(cc);
      setVisible(true);
   }    




   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Images im = new Images();
       im.setResizable(false);
       im.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
    }
```

And this is the main frame that I add panels to.
So main problem is where I paint the card.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

There a number of problems with you entire program, the choice of `null` layouts is a significant one, this is going to cause you a lot of problems.

But, the significant problem you're facing is in your `paint` method

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Random r = new Random();
    String s = "";
    s = str[r.nextInt(str.length)];
    System.out.println(s);
    img = getToolkit().getImage(s);
    g.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, 100, 150, this);
}
```

There are three problems with this method.

1. You should be overriding `paintComponent`, its a safer method for performing custom painting.
2. You're regenerate the image random on each paint cycle.  You have to remember that the your component may be painted for any number of reasons and most outside of your control.  This means that every time the component is painted, a new image is loaded.  You should be assigning a single image to the component when it is constructed and paint that image.
3. The `Graphics` context passed to your component has been translated so that the point 0x0 will be at the top left corner of the component.  This means, all painting is relative.

Your code does this...

```
g.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, 100, 150, this);
```

This means, that the image will be painted at x/y pixels relative to the top/left position of the component.  Instead, you should be painting around the 0x0 position.

In your example, you also do

```
jfrm.setVisible(true);
jfrm.getContentPane().add(cc);
```

This is generally a bad idea, you should switch these two statements, otherwise it will look like nothing has been painted.

You may find it worth while to take a read through

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

**Update with a simple example**

This example is intended to demonstrate the quantity of hits that a `paint` method can take as well as the concept of local coordinate space.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Cards {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cards();
    }

    public Cards() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame jfrm = new JFrame();
                jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                jfrm.setSize(100, 150);
                jfrm.setVisible(true);
                jfrm.add(new TestPane());
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            CardComponent cc = new CardComponent();
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(cc);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            // Simply render the location of the component relative to it's parent.
            for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
                String text = comp.getX() + "x" + comp.getY();
                g.drawString(text, comp.getX(), comp.getY() - fm.getHeight() + fm.getAscent());
            }
        }

    }

    public class CardComponent extends JPanel {

        String[] str;
        Image img;
        private int paintCount;

        public CardComponent() {
            File[] files = new File("C:\\Users\\swhitehead\\Documents\\My Dropbox\\MegaTokyo").listFiles();
            str = new String[files.length];
            for (int index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
                str[index] = files[index].getPath();
            }
            setOpaque(false);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 150);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            paintCount++;
            System.out.println(paintCount);
            super.paint(g);
            Random r = new Random();
            String s = "";
            s = str[r.nextInt(str.length)];
            img = getToolkit().getImage(s);
            // Drawing image in the top left corner of the component
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 150, this);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            String text = "Local 0x0";
            g.drawString(text, 0, fm.getAscent());
        }
    }
}
```

With this example, I was able to get the `paintCount` to 3640 BEFORE I even touched the frame.

Doing image loading in any `paint` method is also a bad idea.  It's expected that `paint` methods should return as quickly as possible, failing to do so will reduce the performance of your program.

Comment: Thanks , I'll read it , but I have few questions.Why setLayout(null) is a bad idea?I know that you need to do some more things then ,but i think it can organize better my interface.I agree that painting 1 image of 1 component is a safer idea ,but I have 52 cards, 52 components ,52 classes ,sounds creepy(or maybe i didn't understand you right).But I didn't understand 3 point ,can you explain pls?Next about image , thanks,but if I put this image into a component and then into a panel with coor (150,150) and image would draw coor(150,150).Would image draw with coor(300,300) ?Thanks for helping!

Comment: Layout managers reduce complexity and take into consideration differences in how different platforms render content. The question is, do you want to program the game or the layout management? The Swing API is designed around the use of layout managers, so you're throwing away a large segment of the API. The problem with the way your paint routine is setup, is that each time the `CardComponent` is painted, it paints a new, random image. This can be done in response to the frame been resized, the mouse been moved over the component, dozens of other issues that you have no control over

Comment: Most modern PC's have, what, 4mb of RAM, I don't think memory is an issue. If you're really worried about, you should only be rendering those cards that are visible anyway, what, maybe 12? Point 3. All painting of a component (within the `paint` method) is done so that the x/y position of 0x0 is the top/left corner of the component. Your setup has the image been painted at 10x150, while the component is only ever 100x150 in size, that means, the images are been rendered outside the component

Comment: *"but i think it can organize better my interface"* - You only think this because you don't truly understand the power of layout managers and what they do for. If you can't find a layout manager that does what you want, look towards using compound layout managers or writing your own.

Comment: What I would do, is change it so that you specify the face that the card should render. Whether that's by directly passing it the image or some constant is up to you.

Comment: But if I have written Layout(null) and doing some details about him,doesn't that mean  I'm ,well,not writing it,but creating my own.Well that's philosophical part :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your code, I don't see a `CardComponent` object, you have to instantiate an object of your `CardComponent` class then add it to your `JFrame` or a component in the `JFrame` like this...

```
Images im = new Images();
PanelButtons pb = new PanelButtons();
CardComponent cc = new CardComponent(x, y);
im.setContentPane(pb);
pb.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
pb.add(cc, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

That's not a working program but hopefully you get the idea. And I did just skim the code so its possible I missed where you instantiate the `CardComponent` object so if you're still having problems try loading the image this way...

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
     super.paint(g);
     Random r = new Random();
     String s = "";
     s = str[r.nextInt(str.length)];
     img = ImageIcon(s).getImage();
     g.drawImage(img,this.x , this.y, 100, 150, this);
 }
```

I just ran your code and I have one more suggestion. In the `CardComponent` set the bounds in the constructor using the `setBounds(x, y, 100, 150)` method and then draw the image from the top left corner (0, 0) to the bottom right (100, 150) or (getWidth(), getHeight()).

Hopefully that helps, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for answer.Well I changed the code a bit, setContentPane to getContentPane.That object that you were saying it was commented ,because it didn't work earlier,but now it does.But now the problem is that 2 panels repainting each other , so that I can see only one of them.What method can give us size of panel or component?As you see I put setSize() ,but it doesn't work or maybe we should put it in place where frame is created?

Comment: I just edited my answer. setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) or setBounds(Rectangle rect) will work with a null layout and is probably your best bet if you're not using a LayoutManager, with a LayoutManager the way I usually set a panels size is by adding this to the constructor...

     public CardComponent() {
          Dimension dim = this.getPreferredSize();
          dim.width = 100;
          dim.height = 150;
          this.setPreferredSize(dim);
     }

Does that answer your question?

Comment: public CardComponent(int x,int y,int height, int width) {
       setOpaque(false);
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
       this.height = height;
       this.width = width;
       setLayout(null);
       setSize(100,150);
       setVisible(true);
       setBounds(this.x,this.y,this.height,this.width);
      
       
      }
      public void paint(Graphics g) {
     super.paint(g);
     Random r = new Random();
     String s = "";
     s = str[r.nextInt(str.length)];
     img = getToolkit().getImage(s);
     g.drawImage(img,0 , 0,100, 150, this);
  } 
This is that you meant?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the setSize() method is redundant if you're calling the setBounds() method. Also its good practice to use methods like getWidth() and getHeight() instead of 100 and 150 when you draw the image, that way if the panel size ever changes you don't have to comb through a ton of code to change all the sizes. For something like this I would use static constant fields. public static final int WIDTH = 100; public static final int HEIGHT = 150;, then use those fields to set the size of the panel, again its just good practice and saves you some trouble if you decide to change your code.